# understanding "this" inside a plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

First of all I'm sorry but I'm a really big beginner.

I dont really understand the "this" in the jquery plugin, was looking a lot but couldn't really find any answer.

here is my plugin (im making this only for practice)

```
jQuery.fn.hoverPlugin = function(){

    var element = this; 

    $(element).animate({"opacity" : ".5"});


        $(element).hover(function(){
            $(element).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
        }, function() {
            $(element).stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
        });
};
```

the call

```
$("img").hoverPlugin();
```

My problem is this way it adds the animate effect on all images. It's okay if animates on all images on the page load, but when I place the mouse over an image, it animates all.

If I write it in the simple way

```
$("img").animate({"opacity" : ".5"});


        $("img").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
        });
```

It works the way I want.

So if a more experienced developer could explain to me how can I make this in my plugin? I would be really happy.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `this` in the `.hoverPlugin` function is referencing the `$('img')` used to call it:

```
jQuery.fn.hoverPlugin = function(){
    var element = this;

    $(element).animate({"opacity" : ".5"});

    $(element).hover(function(){
        $(element).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
    }, function() {
        $(element).stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
    });
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hoverPlugin();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ww7gg/

If you try that with `console` open, you'll see what I mean.

If you just change to this:

```
$(element).hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ww7gg/1/

It works.

And this is better:

```
jQuery.fn.hoverPlugin = function(){
    this
        .animate({"opacity" : ".5"})
        .hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
        });
};
```

You don't need `element`, just use `this` and chain.

http://jsfiddle.net/ww7gg/2/

Comment: really big thanks, for your help, now i understand, and thanks for spearing time on my question.

Answer (score 1):

On your plugin:

var element = this; is a jquery Collection of element(s):

```
jQuery.fn.hoverPlugin = function(){
    var collection = this.animate({"opacity" : ".5"}); //Fade all elements to .5 opactiy.

    collection.each(function() {
        var element = this; // Single element from the collection
            $el = $(element); //Create 1 jquery object and re-use it on the events.

        $el
            .hover(function(){
                $el.stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
            }, function() {
                $el.stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
            });
    });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.fn.hoverPlugin = function(){

    var element = this; //this is already wrapped as jquery object e.g it will refer to $("img") in your case

    element.animate({"opacity" : ".5"});


        element.hover(function(){
            element.stop(true,true).animate({"opacity" : "1"});
        }, function() {
            element.stop().animate({"opacity" : ".5"});
        });
};
```

and use it

```
$("img").hoverPlugin();
```